# Woocommerce - How to pass quantity into Add to cart button

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

How can i make add-to-cart button with custom quantity attribute?

I can add:

```
?add-to-cart=335,338,339&quantity=3,2,1
```

to my page link and it works well, but i want to make button with those attributes.

Default one:

```
<button type="submit" name="add-to-cart" value="332,333,338&quantity=3,2,1"  class="single_add_to_cart_button button alt">Add to cart</button>
```

adds products, but always 1, quantity field don't work.

I know i can pass those attributes by `<a href="...">` but i want to do it proper way.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the attribute `data-quantity` in ur `<a>` tag.

Example - add 3 units from Product with ID 332:
`<button type="submit" name="add-to-cart" value="332" class="single_add_to_cart_button" data-quantity="3">Add to cart</button>`